# JSF + Primefaces + StreamedContent + documentViewer + ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces 5.2 with extensions 3.1. 
I have my datatable and on click on each row I'd like to display modal and in this modal use documentViewer which will display document based on parameter passed from selected row.

With this I'm invoking my modal from within datatable

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":previewDataForm" oncomplete="$('.previewDataModal').modal();" immediate="true">
        <f:param name="pdfFile" value="#{row.dataPath}"/>
</p:ajax>
```

this is my modal:

```
<b:modal id="previewDataModal" title="Preview" styleClass="orderPreviewModalPseudoClass">
    <h:form id="previewDataForm">
        <pe:documentViewer height="550" value="#{contentStreamHelperBean.pdfFromFileSystem}" />
    </h:form>
</b:modal>
```

and this is my stream helper

```
@Component("contentStreamHelperBean")
@Scope("request")
public class ContentStreamHelperBean extends BaseBean {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ContentStreamHelperBean.class);


    public StreamedContent getPdfFromFileSystem() {
        String pdfFile = getRequestAttribute("pdfFile");
        if (getFacesContext().getCurrentPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE) {
            return new DefaultStreamedContent();
        } else {

            if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(pdfFile))
                try {
                    return new DefaultStreamedContent(new FileInputStream(new File(pdfFile)), "application/pdf");
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    log.error("Unable to get pdf", e);
                }
        }
        return new DefaultStreamedContent();
    }
}
```

Problem is, that when onclick is invoked I can't get pdfFile param in my ContentStreamHelper so:

1. how to pass parameter from dataTable rowSelect to my backingBean?
2. is this good approach how to display PDF with documentViewer?